# Run multiple prerequisite methods in parallel before continuing

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have an application in which I have multiple slow running prerequisite methods I need to call in order to have the data I need to continue.

To try to speed this up I am doing this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> processOptions = null;
Dictionary<string, string> businessAreas = null;
Dictionary<string, string> requirementLevels = null;
List<TemplateSection> sections = null;
List<TemplateVersion> versions = null;

var prerequisiteTasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();

prerequisiteTasks.Add(new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => sections = GetSectionsInTreeForm(latestVersionGuid)));
prerequisiteTasks.Add(new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => versions = GetTemplateVersions(templateId)));
prerequisiteTasks.Add(new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => processOptions = GetOptionSetProcessPhaseTypes()));
prerequisiteTasks.Add(new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => businessAreas = GetOptionSetBusinessAreaTypes()));
prerequisiteTasks.Add(new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => requirementLevels = GetOptionSetRequirementLevelTypes()));

prerequisiteTasks.ForEach(x => x.Start());
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(prerequisiteTasks.ToArray());
```

Each of the methods above can take anything from 2-5 seconds to complete.
Is there a nicer way of doing this, or is this something I shouldent do?

P.S. the code as is works great and decreases the time used by around 30%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is [Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, string> processOptions = null;
Dictionary<string, string> businessAreas = null;
Dictionary<string, string> requirementLevels = null;
List<TemplateSection> sections = null;
List<TemplateVersion> versions = null;


Parallel.Invoke(() => sections = GetSectionsInTreeForm(latestVersionGuid),
                () => versions = GetTemplateVersions(templateId),
                () => processOptions = GetOptionSetProcessPhaseTypes(),
                () => businessAreas = GetOptionSetBusinessAreaTypes(),
                () => requirementLevels = GetOptionSetRequirementLevelTypes());
```

---

It should be pointed out that these tasks run in threads from the thread pool (in both cases: `Task` and `Parallel.Invoke`). That's OK for few tasks with a run time from 2-5 seconds, but for long running tasks it is better to use a Task object with [TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) to run the task in it's own thread. Otherwise the threadpool threads will be blocked for other short running tasks.

`Task`s provide a more granular control but that is not required in your case so I would prefer the simpler `Parallel.Invoke` variant.

Comment: Changed my code to this, looks much cleaner and easier to see what is happening.